# I have CUDA and CUDNN installed, but still getting this error

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0, nvidia

> ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu' from
> 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations'
> (C:\Users\astar\anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow
> 2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\strategy_combinations.py)

I have required CUDA=10.2 and CudNN=7.6 for tensorflow=2.3.0. But when I run TensorFlow GPU to test if I have Cuda installed, I am getting this error, is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow 2.3.0 with GPU support requires CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6. Uninstall version 10.2 and install the compatible version.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux